# How to unload ActiveX's ocx without terminating main application to allow the ocx to be overwritten?

Tags: c++, mfc, vb6, activex, visual-c++-6

I have `ActiveX` controls implemented in `VB6` and are instantiated inside `MFC42` application.

I have a tree view structure on the left panel of the application and when different items in the tree are selected, different `ActiveX` are loaded accordingly on the right panel to display the details of the selected item.

Whenever I want to modify the `VB` code for the `ActiveX`, I will need to restart the application. This greatly interrupts the development flow since the application starts pretty slowly.

In some `ActiveX` we have dummy code/data to allow the `ActiveX` to be executed inside Internet Explorer, which is faster to load, but not all of our `ActiveX` have it.

I am expecting that when I click different item in the tree view, the previous `ActiveX` is unloaded and I can overwrite it with a new version.

If the ActiveX has never been instantiated/displayed, I am able to replace the `ocx` while the application is still running.

I searched in the internet and found [two](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/controls/article.php/c5537/Dynamic-creation-and-placement-of-ActiveX-controls.htm#control_creation) [articles](http://fruitfruit.blogspot.sg/2004/11/createcontrol-and-destroy-at-runtime.html) on `ActiveX`, both of them suggest that the proper way to clean up is to:

```cpp
m_pControl = new CWnd;
m_pControl->CreateControl(strControlProgid,
                          "",
                          WS_VISIBLE, 
                          rc,
                          this,
                          5000,
                          NULL,
                          FALSE,
                          NULL);
// ...
m_pControl->DestroyWindow();
delete m_pControl;
```

The `ActiveX`s we have are already destroyed using this method but I still need to exit the application in order to overwrite the `ocx`.

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, for VC++ 6 (with MFC42), instead of `CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx` which is mentioned by [Noseratio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898571/109747); I can use `CoFreeUnusedLibraries` which will work without delay for Single Threaded Apartement (STA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the COM reference counting works correctly in your app, you could try forcing to unload the no-longer-in-use ActiveX DLL with `CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx`.